# cannot compile Room DB TypeConverter for kotlin.time.Duration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

only when creating a `androidx.room.TypeConverter` for a `kotlin.time.Duration`, I get the following compiler error:

```
MillisKotlinDurationConverter.java:6: error: Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods.
public final class MillisKotlinDurationConverter {
             ^
```

the code for `MillisKotlinDurationConverter.kt` is shown below, and is no different for any of the other `@TypeConverter`s in the project:

```kotlin
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.milliseconds

class MillisKotlinDurationConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun convert(value: Duration?): Long? = value?.inWholeMilliseconds

    @TypeConverter
    fun convert(value: Long?): Duration? = value?.milliseconds
}
```

I also didn't forget to add it into the `@TypeConverters` array for the DB

```kotlin
@Database(
    entities = [
        ...
    ],
    version = DATABASE_VERSION
)
@TypeConverters(
    ...,
    MillisKotlinDurationConverter::class,
    ...
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: kotlin.time.Duration is a value class. In runtime Duration is just old Long. If I remember well, Room compiler/interpreter still is not capable to handle `Kotlin value classes`.

Comment: @ocos, you seem, to be right! `Duration` is declared as `public value class Duration`. I also just tested to see if it would compile without a `TypeConverter` for `kotlin.time.Duration` too (since it is already a `Long`, I think?), and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

reposting correct answer from comments as an actual answer....

Solution is to store into the database something other than the Kotlin `Duration`, and convert it to Kotlin `Duration` when needed.

`kotlin.time.Duration` is a value class. At runtime, it's actually a `Long`. today, Room compiler/interpreter is not yet capable of handling Kotlin value classes.